# Request Dialog checkbox option "don't ask before sending..."

Tags: checkbox, dialog, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've seen in The Sims Social app a checkbox option on the request dialog that says: "don't ask before sending The Sims Social requests to <USER>."

I haven't found this feature on the Facebook API Docs, and I ´d like to know how to enable it on my app.

Answer (score 1):

Flavia

Refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#custom_fields
You should be able to specify any custom fields you wish to include.

```
{"name":"the-name", "description": "the-description", "type": "option-type"}
```

or if options.

```
{"name":"the-name", "description": "the-description", "type": "option-type", "options": {"name":"value","name":"value"}}
```

---

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="https://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo" 
 fields='[
   {"name":"name"},
   {"name":"foo","description":"Type foo","type":"text"},
   {"name":"bar","description":"Type bar","type":"text"},
   {"name":"facebooker","description":"Pick Paul","type":"select","options": {"coder":"Paul","pm":"Austin","partners":"Cat"}}]' 
 onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration>
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is most likely a flag they use internally to know whether the user would like to receive app-generated requests, not a Facebook-implemented piece of functionality. For more information on app-generated requests, try here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

Answer (score 1):

set *frictionlessRequests* as *true* will do that.

```
FB.init({
        appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        frictionlessRequests : true,
        oauth: true
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be shocked, but adding

layout: "iframe"

To th FB.ui request as param should solve your problem. The FB dialog will appear with the checkbox you want.

```
       FB.ui(
                {
                    method:  "apprequests", 
                    filters: ["app_non_users"],
                    layout:  "iframe",                   
                    data:    "invite",
                    title:   heading,
                    message: text,
                    picture: pictureUrl,
                    caption: text
                },
                function(response) {
                  if (response && response.request_ids) {
                    // the user has successfuly carried out the action
                    fbHandleResponse(response);
                  } else {
                    // user cancelled the action
                    fbHandleFailure();
                  }
                }
            );
```

Cheers!
Jakub